# Time series factor model with one series more frequent

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models, unevenly-spaced-time-series

Let's say I have two time series, one of which updates more frequently than the other:

$x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_t,\dots$

$y_0,y_{10},y_{20},\dots,y_{10t},\dots$

I want to fit a model to this that predicts $y$ from $x$ (and possibly from previous values of $y$) at each of the values $1,2,3,\dots$, i.e. it gives a prediction even for values of $y$ for which we won't make an observation (equivalently, assume that there are true values for $y$ at every value of $t$, but we only observe it at $t=0,10,20,\dots$)

Is there a canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cannonical way is probably [MIDAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_data_sampling) regression. There is a Matlab toolbox for estimating, available upon request from the [author Eric Ghysels](http://www.unc.edu/~eghysels/). You might look into [user guide](http://www.unc.edu/~eghysels/papers/MIDAS_Usersguide_Version8.pdf) of this toolbox, since it has a review of all literature on MIDAS.

The wikipedia page also talks about connection with Kalman filters, so @F. Tussel observation is spot on.

**Update** There is now also an R package [midasr](http://mpiktas.github.io/midasr/) to estimate MIDAS regression.

Answer (score 4):

I would cast the model in state-space form. Then there is no problem if one of the variables is observed more frequently than the other, or the observation times are irregular: the Kalman filter deals with missing and partially observed variables gracefully.

Without details on the exact kind of relationships you aim to model it is difficult to be more specific.